# looking for a searching in excel programm

Tags: c#, excel, search, readfile

im looking for programm that reads Excel documents and can search for a word in that document
thank you
with this code am able to read all Cells but i want to add the function that i could search for a word that i input in(console.readLine)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ReadFromExcelComponente
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //lese den excel
            Excel.Application ExcelApp;
            Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
            Excel.Range range;
            int row = 0;              
            int column = 0;             

            ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
            workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Map", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = worksheet.UsedRange;

            List<String> myList = new List<string>();
            for (row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (column = 1; column <= range.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Coulmn Number: " + column + "--> " + (range.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range).Value2);
                    myList.Add(range.Cells[column].ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(myList[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(range.Cells[2, 2].Value);




            workbook.Close(true, null, null);
            ExcelApp.Quit();

            Console.ReadKey();

        } 


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I assume you are not getting any errors. If you have the list `myList` that holds the cell values from the worksheet, then, couldn’t you “search” for the word you are looking for in `myList`? Also, what do you want to happen if you DO find a match for the searched for word? In addition, Is it required for you to use `Interop.Excel`? I am just saying there are other third-party Excel readers that do a much better job.

Comment: Lastly, you should “release” the COM objects your code creates i.e. Excel app and workbook. Closing the workbook and quitting the app is not enough… if you run your code numerous times, then, look in the Windows Task Manger… I am betting you will see many Excel apps running in the background. This is referred to as a “leaking” resource and you want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ReadFromExcelComponente
{


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the word you want to search for:");
        string SearchWord = Console.ReadLine();
        //lese den excel
        Excel.Application ExcelApp;
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        Excel.Range range;
        int row = 0;              
        int column = 0;             

        ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Map", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = worksheet.UsedRange;

        for (row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (column = 1; column <= range.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
               if(range.Range(row, column).Value = SearchWord)
                 {
                  Console.WriteLine("Found word!");
                  break;
               }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(myList[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(range.Cells[2, 2].Value);




        workbook.Close(true, null, null);
        ExcelApp.Quit();
        ExcelApp = null;
        Console.ReadKey();

    } 
}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When “your code” starts the Excel application and opens an Excel file… then YOUR CODE becomes responsible for “releasing” the COM objects it creates… namely… the workbook and the Excel application.

If you do not release those objects, as your current code doesn’t, then those objects will remain in memory as active objects and basically never get released. Even if your code closes the file and Excel app… YOUR CODE still has to explicitly “release” the COM object. Granted, if you reboot the machine or even quit the application… then those objects may/will get released.

Fortunately, it is not difficult to manage the Excel resources. One fairly straight forward approach is to use a `try/catch/finally` statement to manage the resources. The `try` portion is where we put ALL the code that deals with the Excel file(s). The `catch` portion is used to obviously catch the exceptions. And the `finally` portion is where we would put the code to “release” the Excel COM objects.

With this approach, we should be able to rest a little easier knowing that the COM objects will STILL be released… even if the code crashes while working with the Excel file.

Next, I am aware that sometimes you must use `Interop` to work with Excel files and I have used it often and know it can be awkward. Not to mention that `Interop` is notoriously SLOW especially when dealing with large Excel files. My point is that if you DO have a choice, I would highly recommend a third-party Excel library. There are many to chose from and some are free.

Getting down from my soap box…

Looking at your code, there is one thing I am not following when the code gets the `UsedRange` from the Excel worksheet…

```
range = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

This `range` is a basic Excel Range object containing all the “used” cells in the worksheet. So far so good…

But… later we see a double `for` loop through the `range`’s rows and columns. The code then puts the values of each cell into (`List<string>`) `myList`. This will work however it seems unnecessary. Even if you want to search for a word in all the cells, there is no need to put the cell values into a list… you ALREADY  have the cells in the `range` variable! In other words, instead of adding the words to a list, just loop through `range` and search for it.

When I say you have the `range` to work with, this means the `Excel.Range` object. And you already know you can easily loop through that `range` object as your code demonstrates… HOWEVER… IF `range` is large, THEN, you will note a significant performance hit. Bottom line is that “looping” through `Excel.Range`’es is expensive and slow.

Basically we want to minimize any looping through the `range`. One possible solution is to cast the `range` into a two (2) dimensional `Object` array. THEN, do all the looping through the `Object` array, which should be significantly faster and it makes the code a little easier to read.

Therefore, the line of code…

```
range = worksheet.UsedRange;
```

may end up looking like…

```
range = worksheet.UsedRange;
object[,] worksheetValues = (object[,])range.Cells.Value;
```

Now, we can loop through the `worksheetValues` array instead of the `range` itself.

This “should” replace the `mylist` variable as it is not needed… all the values are in the `worksheetValues` array.

Now that we have a simple object array to “search” through… then all we need is a search term to look for. If we get the search term from the user, then we could create a method that takes that search term and the array to search through and return all the X and Y coordinates of the cells that the search term matched. This method may look something like…

```
private static List<Point> FindWordInArray(string target, object[,] data) {
  List<Point> foundIndexes = new List<Point>();
  for (int row = 1; row <= data.GetLength(0); row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= data.GetLength(1); col++) {
      if (data[row, col] != null) {
        if (data[row, col].ToString().Equals(target)) {
          foundIndexes.Add(new Point { X = col, Y = row });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return foundIndexes;
}


public class Point {
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

I am aware the `Point` class may not be needed and is only there to simplify the example.

Below is a small yet complete example of what is described above. This includes setting up the `try/catch/finally` code along with releasing the COM objects.

NOTE: Excel starts array indexing at 1. Therefore the object array `worksheetValues` will start at index 1.

```
Excel.Application ExcelApp = null;
Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
Excel.Worksheet worksheet= null;
Excel.Range range = null;
string searchWord = "";
try {
  ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
  workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Map", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
  worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
  range = worksheet.UsedRange;
  object[,] worksheetValues = (object[,])range.Cells.Value;
  Console.WriteLine("There are " + worksheetValues.GetLength(0) + " Rows and " + worksheetValues.GetLength(1) + " Columns");
  for (int row = 1; row <= worksheetValues.GetLength(0); row++) {
    Console.Write("Row " + row + ": ");
    for (int col = 1; col <= worksheetValues.GetLength(1); col++) {
      if (worksheetValues[row, col] != null) {
        Console.Write(worksheetValues[row, col]);
      }
      else {
        Console.Write(" - ");
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Type the word you want to search for...");
  searchWord = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
  List<Point> foundItems = FindWordInArray(searchWord, worksheetValues);
  foreach (Point point in foundItems) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found at Row: " + point.Y + " - Col: " + point.X);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  Console.WriteLine("Excel error: " + ex.Message);
}
finally {
  if (range != null) {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
  }
  if (worksheet != null) {
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
  }
  if (workbook != null) {
    workbook.Close(true, null, null);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
  }
  if (ExcelApp != null) {
    ExcelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp);
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.